# Who is this guy?

Tags: olliolli

At the end of certain levels in OlliOlli, there are a bunch of extra grinds spanning beyond the end that you can score tricks on and also collect a Golden Skateboard.

And the end of that, however, there's this chap just standing there. I can only assume it's an easter egg of sorts.

[image: Mysterious shade-wearing chap at the end of a level]

It seems like this guy is the only sprite with what seems to resemble an actual human face, but I don't get who this is supposed to be.

**Who is he?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I unpacked the game data, in the file "\tilesheets\urban.png" he looks like this:

[image: The guy in game files]

After some mindstorming, I thought that it was John Ribbins, which is part of the development team and contacted him on twitter.

Here is his current twitter picture:

[image: Developer John Ribbins]

After some while, he replied saying that [it was him](https://twitter.com/flappyfingers/status/703902837743427584).